# AngularJS Redirect for Authorization

Tags: jquery, angularjs, firebase

I've built a login system with angularfire and firebase.

I have a function that is called when the user is logged in and multiple other times. Checks if authData exists and registers the user as logged in if it exists.

```
fbRef.onAuth(authDataCallback);
function authDataCallback(authData) {
    if (authData) {
        $scope.loggedIn = true;
    } else {
        $scope.loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

I also have routes set up

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: '',
        templateUrl: '/company/pages/account/pages/dashboard.php',
    })
    .when('/dashboard', {
        controller: '',
        templateUrl: '/company/pages/account/pages/dashboard.php',
    })
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'Authorization',
        templateUrl: '/company/pages/account/pages/login.php',
    })
    .when('/register', {
        controller: 'Authorization',
        templateUrl: '/company/pages/account/pages/register.php',
    })
})
```

I want every page but the login and register pages to be restricted to logged in users only. I want the user to be redirected to the login page if `$scope.loggedIn` returns as false.

I have tried many solutions on the internet, but none have worked for me. Most of them have resulted in limit exceeded errors.

How would I restrict access in my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the "loggedIn" variable has changes

```
    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){

        fbRef.onAuth(authDataCallback);

        $scope.loggedIn = null;

        function authDataCallback(authData) {
            $scope.loggedIn = authData ? true : false
        }

        $scope.$watch("loggedIn", function(val){

            val === false && $location.path("/login");

        });

    });
```

Comment: Why to watch loggedIn user when you can simply do the same thing in callback?

Comment: specifically because, I think that the function is taking it as an example, and possibly authDataCallback function is not part of angular and really he want is to check the variable 'loggedIn'. In fact, I also thought

Comment: There is no need to watch for a logged in state inside of a controller. You should always resolve a user into a controller. AngularFire has specific functions for this like $waitForAuth.

Answer (score 0):

In our controller, check in callback and accordingly redirect.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

  fbRef.onAuth(authDataCallback);

  function authDataCallback(authData) {
      authData ? $location.path("/dashboard") : $location.path("/login");
  }

}]);
```

Comment: This only results in a login re-direct about every other time the base url is visited. Not fool proof. Can't work.

Comment: What else you need? Mention that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

### The plan:

Another possible solution is to setup a variable called like `loginRequired` from the `$routeProvider`
and from `$routeChangeStart` check the variable against `$rootScope.loggedIn`.

Unfortunately as you can see you have to move `$scope.loggedIn` to `$rootScope.loggedIn`.

### One possible implementation:

In the router :

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: '',
            templateUrl: '/company/pages/account/pages/dashboard.php',
            loginRequired: true
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            controller: '',
            templateUrl: '/company/pages/account/pages/dashboard.php',
            loginRequired: true
        })
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'Authorization',
            templateUrl: '/company/pages/account/pages/login.php',
            loginRequired: false
        })
        .when('/register', {
            controller: 'Authorization',
            templateUrl: '/company/pages/account/pages/register.php',
            loginRequired: true
        })
    })
```

In `app.run` :

```
app.run(
    ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
            if ($rootScope.loginRequired && !$rootScope.loggedIn) {
                $location.path("/login");
            }
        });

    }]);
```